# Making a Graph/Curve with Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, input, bezier

I am trying to make a program that you can can input numbers into, and it creates a graph based off of those (like Desmos, but the numbers you input don't need to be formatted like (1, 0) and you can control the spacing of the numbers). I am coding this in Javascript, and HTML for the actual inputs and canvas.

I have tried using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp) website as a foundation to help me create the curve.

Here is the combined Javascript and HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <label></label>
  <input id="numbers" value="Numbers">
  <button onClick="refresh()">Submit</button>
</form>
<form>
  <label></label>
  <input id="spacing" value="Spacing">
  <button onClick="refresh()">Submit</button>
</form>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>
  refresh()
  numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
  function refresh(){
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(numbers);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Please note that I know that the canvas does not work (the variable `numbers` isn's working, any help?), but my main concern is that [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp) code doesn't create a graph like I want it to. I want to type in numbers, and have it plot invisible points `x` numbers above the "ground" (the bottom of the canvas) and then use bezier to make a curve go through those invisible points (don't make the points, that was the only way I could think of explaining it).

Comment: When the code is loaded and run, the `numbers` variable is given a value. This variable is only set once. It is set after the first time `refresh` is called.

Comment: @enhzflep, how would I do this? Also, how do I properly set the value of `numbers`? 
Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: What if the first thing you did in the `refresh` function was to get fresh data, specifically, by setting variable that's then used a few lines later?

Comment: @enhzflep, i'll try that! However, my main concern is plotting the points so that the graph is correct. I would like the input labeled "Numbers" to control the y-axis, and the other, "Spacing" to control the x-axis and the space between the points.

Comment: If you're using HTML5, elements with an `id` _already exist_ as variables in global scope, by that name. No need to `document.getElementById` them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Also remember that _everything in HTML is strings_ so even if you're pulling data from a form input field, and even though you say it's type="number", the data _will be string data_ and you need to convert it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermanst thanks!! I will remember that

Comment: Also remember that a `<button>` inside a form is, _by default_ a form submit button. Unless you're _actually posting data to a server_ don't use a `<form>` element. Put your inputs and button in a div or the like. So with that said: if you still want to figure this out, it's a good idea to update your post. If not, then it's a good idea to delete your post =)

Answer (score 0):

For my internship, I was asked to develop a lightweight web application for some of our internal operations.  One of the functions I wanted to include was a graph/chart that plotted Sales data for a selected employee.  I also wanted to be able to change the resolution of the chart's x-axis such that I could view Sales by day, week, month, quarter, or year.

Here's what I came up with using just basic JavaScript and HTML Canvas.

Regarding the `fix_dpi()` function (that may be confusing to new coders, like myself), here was an article explaining what it is and why you will want to adjust for it: https://medium.com/wdstack/fixing-html5-2d-canvas-blur-8ebe27db07da .

Also, note that my `drawYTicks()` function has a special case for the "50K" and "500K" labels.  If you need something a little more general, just copy the code of from `drawXTicks()` and make the minor changes necessary for it's domain.

Code:

```
<script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
    let xOrig = canvas.width * 0.15;
    let yOrig = canvas.height * 0.85;
    let xLen = canvas.width * 0.7;
    let yLen = canvas.height * 0.7;

    function fix_dpi() {
        let style = {
            height() {
                return +getComputedStyle(canvas).getPropertyValue('height').slice(0, -2);
            },
            width() {
                return +getComputedStyle(canvas).getPropertyValue('width').slice(0, -2);
            }
        }
        canvas.setAttribute('width', style.width() * dpi);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', style.height() * dpi);
        xOrig = canvas.width * 0.15;
        yOrig = canvas.height * 0.85;
        xLen = canvas.width * 0.7;
        yLen = canvas.height * 0.7;
    }

    function draw() {
        fix_dpi();  //fixes dpi for sharper image...

        var dataSet = // int[][] containing the data.
        var xLabs = // a string[] containing x-labels.
        var yLabs = // a string[] containing y-labels.
        var range = // an integer expressing the top of your range (x-axis);
        var domain = // an integer expressing the top of your domain (y-axis)

        console.log(xLabs);
        console.log(xLabs.length);
        console.log(yLabs);
        console.log(yLabs.length);

        drawChartTitle("Employee (Total) Sales History");
        fillDataSpace(dataSet, range, domain, '#3F3');
        drawDataLine(dataSet, range, domain, '#000');
        drawDataPoints(dataSet, range, domain, '#F00');
        drawXTicks(xLabs);
        drawYTicks(yLabs);
        drawAxes();
    }

    function drawChartTitle(title) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.font = '24px Times New Roman';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(title, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height * 0.1);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawAxes(color='#000') {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.moveTo(xOrig, (yOrig - yLen));
        ctx.lineTo(xOrig, yOrig);
        ctx.lineTo((xOrig + xLen),yOrig);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawYTicks(yLabs) {
        //Note:  two of the ticks have to be handled separately
        //for this program, 50K and 500K.
        ctx.save();
        let tickLen = canvas.height / 50;
        let yDivs = yLen / (yLabs.length - 1);
        let tickX = xOrig - tickLen / 2;
        let labX = xOrig - tickLen;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.font = '12px Times New Roman';
        ctx.textAlign = 'right';

        if (yLabs.length >= 4) {
            yDivs = yLen / (yLabs.length - 3);
            //Draw million dollar ticks and labels
            for (let i = 3; i < yLabs.length; i++) {
                let tickY = yOrig - yDivs * (i-2);
                ctx.moveTo(tickX, tickY);
                ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), tickY);
            }
            for (let i = 3; i < yLabs.length; i++) {
                let labY = yOrig - yDivs * (i-2) + 4;
                ctx.fillText(yLabs[i], labX, labY);
            }
            //Draw 50K and 500K
            let fifty = yOrig - yDivs * 0.1;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, fifty);
            ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), fifty);
            ctx.fillText(yLabs[1], labX, fifty + 4);

            let fHundredK = yOrig - yDivs * 0.5;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, fHundredK);
            ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), fHundredK);
            ctx.fillText(yLabs[2], labX, fHundredK + 4);
        }
        else if (yLabs.length == 3) {
            yDivs = yLen / (yLabs.length - 2);
            //Draw 50K and 500K only
            let fifty = yOrig - yDivs * 0.1;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, fifty);
            ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), fifty);
            ctx.fillText(yLabs[1], labX, fifty + 4);

            let fHundredK = yOrig - yDivs;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, fHundredK);
            ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), fHundredK);
            ctx.fillText(yLabs[2], labX, fHundredK + 4);
        }
        else {
            //Draw 50K only
            let fifty = yOrig - yDivs;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, fifty);
            ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), fifty);
            ctx.fillText(yLabs[1], labX, fifty + 4);
        }

        let zero = yOrig;
        ctx.moveTo(tickX, zero);
        ctx.lineTo((tickX + tickLen), zero);
        ctx.fillText(yLabs[0], labX, zero + 4);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawXTicks(xLabs) {
        ctx.save();
        let tickLen = canvas.height / 50;
        let xDivs = xLen / (xLabs.length - 1);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
        for (let i = 0; i < xLabs.length; i++) {
            let tickX = xOrig + xDivs * i;
            let tickY = yOrig + tickLen / 2;
            ctx.moveTo(tickX, tickY);
            ctx.lineTo(tickX, (tickY - tickLen));
        }
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();

        for (let i = 0; i < xLabs.length; i++) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
            ctx.font = '12px Times New Roman';
            ctx.textAlign = 'right';
            ctx.translate((canvas.width*0.15) + (xDivs * i), canvas.height*0.15);
            ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
            let labY = canvas.height * 0.52;
            let labX = -canvas.width * 0.38;
            ctx.fillText(xLabs[i], labX, labY);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }

    function drawDataPoints(coords, maxX, maxY, color='#000') {
        ctx.save();
        if (coords.length >= 2) {
            let xScale = xLen / maxX;
            let yScale = yLen / maxY;
            let pointCir = canvas.height / 200;

            ctx.beginPath();
            for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
                let xp = xOrig + coords[i][0] * xScale;
                let yp = yOrig - coords[i][1] * yScale;

                ctx.moveTo(xp, yp);
                ctx.arc(xp, yp, pointCir, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            }
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
            ctx.font = '24px Sans-Serif';

            ctx.fillText('There is no data to display', (xOrig + xLen * 0.3), (yOrig - yLen * 0.5));
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawDataLine(coords, maxX, maxY, color='#000') {
        ctx.save();
        if (coords.length >= 2) {
            let xScale = xLen / maxX;
            let yScale = yLen / maxY;
            let xp = xOrig + coords[0][0] * xScale;
            let yp = yOrig - coords[0][1] * yScale;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(xp, yp);
            for (let i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
                xp = xOrig + coords[i][0] * xScale;
                yp = yOrig - coords[i][1] * yScale;

                ctx.lineTo(xp, yp);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
            ctx.font = '24px Sans-Serif';

            ctx.fillText('There is no data to display', (xOrig + xLen * 0.3), (yOrig - yLen * 0.5));
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function fillDataSpace(coords, maxX, maxY, color = '#00F') {
        ctx.save();
        if (coords.length >= 2) {
            let xScale = xLen / maxX;
            let yScale = yLen / maxY;
            let xp = xOrig + coords[0][0] * xScale;
            let yp = yOrig - coords[0][1] * yScale;

            var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(xOrig, yOrig - yLen, xOrig + xLen, yOrig);
            lingrad.addColorStop(0, '#FFF');
            lingrad.addColorStop(0.5, color);
            lingrad.addColorStop(1, '#FFF');

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(xp, yp);
            for (let i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
                xp = xOrig + coords[i][0] * xScale;
                yp = yOrig - coords[i][1] * yScale;

                ctx.lineTo(xp, yp);
            }
            ctx.lineTo(xOrig + xLen, yOrig);
            ctx.lineTo(xOrig, yOrig);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = lingrad;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;
            ctx.fill();
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
            ctx.font = '24px Sans-Serif';

            ctx.fillText('There is no data to display', (xOrig + xLen * 0.3), (yOrig - yLen * 0.5));
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
</script>
```

Here's what it looks like with some rendered data:  [Employee Sales Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdaWY.png)

Final note:  I handled the collection of the data points and data labels using a static class object within my program, and passed this object to the HTML (Razor) page for my project.  But, this solution should work if you have a way to get the data to your JS functions.  If nothing else, you can start playing with this by defining the `dataSet`, `xLabs`, `yLabs`, `range`, and `domain` variables first and then figuring out how to pass larger data sets to the function later.